# TypeScript does not show compile error on function type mismatch

Tags: typescript

I am expecting that TypeScript should throw compile error here but it eats this code without any errors ([playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=interface%20FancyFunction%20%7B%0A%09(sql%3A%20string)%3A%20number%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20foo(arg%3A%20FancyFunction)%20%7B%0A%09%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20badFunc()%3A%20number%20%7B%0A%09return%201%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Afoo(badFunc)%3B%0A)):

```
interface FancyFunction {
    (sql: string): number;
}

function foo(arg: FancyFunction) {

}

function badFunc(): number {
    return 1;
};

foo(badFunc); // <<<<<< why no type mismatch??
```

`badFunc` does not have type of `FancyFunction` so what is going on here?

Comment: Duplicate, and also answered in the TypeScript FAQ: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters

Comment: A *good* duplicate though IMHO. This question's code sample made immediate sense to me, where the dupe target's code took me a minute to grasp.